# How to add a menu bar to a UICollectionViewController embedded in a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation controller who's root is a Collection view controller. I'm trying to add a tab menu bar at the top just under the navigation bar and before a scrollable collection view. The tab bar would have two buttons that show the appropriate collection view. Below is the image of the screen. Any help would be great and preferably Swift.

[image: screen of collectionviewcontroller]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the UICollectionViewController to a UIViewController and then add the delegates for UICollectionViewController to the UIViewController. Like this:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>
```

Comment: Then add a subview with 2 buttons for the menu bar and the uicollectionview as another subview?